# How to show data in a table view cell which is fed through a text field and round rect button

Tags: ipad, uitableview, uibutton, uitextfield

[image]

In my iPad application, on a single view there is one text field, 2 round rect buttons and a table view.

On pressing those buttons a popup appears and user selects a value from that popover, also that value becomes the title of the button. There is one text field to which user can feed some value.

What I want to do is, when user feeds some thing in that text field and selects some value by pressing those buttons, all these 3 things should appear on a cell of the table view.
Similarly when user again feeds data in text field and buttons, then this data should appear on second cell of the table view.

Please consider attached image cut out from the actual mockup of my project.

I have very less idea of doing this task.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Thanks and best regards,

PC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do what you want to do via `UITableView`'s [`reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadRowsAtIndexPaths%3awithRowAnimation%3a) function.

Just make sure you're setting the right cell that you want to update (which you pass along in the "indexPath" parameter) and you can update that cell (if it's visible) to reflect the data you want to be updated.